# chrome.runtime.onMessage not receiving messages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my first extension where I want to send a message from contentScript to popup.js script but the message is not received.

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function() {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: 'popup.html'});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'contentScript.js'
    });
  }, {url: [{hostSuffix : 'domain.com'}]});
});
```

contentScript.js (here tried to put it outside of the load script but didn't help)

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
  s.remove();
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    return true;
  });
};
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HI</h1>
    <section id='red'></section>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("HEREEEE");
    document.getElementById("red").innerHTML += "Hello";
  }
);
```

Manifest

```
{
  "name": "new extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "cookies", "sessions", "declarativeContent", "webNavigation", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "script.js"
  ]
}
```

background.js is waiting for a page to be fully loaded, then execute contentScript and setPopup for browserAction popup.html - there is script for popup.js. The contentScript will execute another script and will send a message. The popup.js is listening for the message but it never arrive. Do you know why? Is it because of the background.js events?

My intention is to wait for certain page (can't use pageAction because it does not allow me to add badget) and then update the extension popup with appropriate content.

Comment: 1) The popup is running only when shown so you can't send any messages to it when it's not. 2) executeScript without a tab id parameter will always inject in the active tab which might be totally different from the navigated tab, 3) In a non-persistent background script all recurrent listeners must be registered in the top context so that they re-register every time the script awakes, but yours doesn't.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm could you please suggest some events or sequences to use for this given task? Quite struggling with the set up. Thanks!

Comment: For the purpose of updating the icon's badge you can simply use an onMessage listener in the background script, so it'll invoke chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText. I also see no need for webNavigation API: simply declare a content script in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm I need to get a global variable from a page and pass it to the popup so I can display length of the variable accurately. The variable is created when the page is fully loaded

Comment: Well, then simply run the content script from your popup script, you don't need the background script at all.